# how do i know in advance that the buffer size is enough in nanopb?

Tags: size, buffer, nanopb

im trying to use nanopb, according to the example:
https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.c

the buffer size is initialized to 128:

`uint8_t buffer[128];`

my question is how do i know (in advance) this `128-length buffer` is enough to transmit my message? how to decide a proper(enough but not waste too much due to over-large) size of buffer before initial (or coding) it?

looks like a noob question :) , but thx for your quick suggestion.

Comment: do i need just do some simple calculations?
e.g. https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/examples/simple/simple.proto
the msg is defined by `int32`, so payload `int32 <= 4 bytes` , with maybe some header/keywords/MagicWords of nanopb decoding, saying 16 bytes, so `4+16 = 20bytes` is ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When possible, nanopb adds a define in the generated `.pb.h` file that has the maximum encoded size of a message. In the file `examples/simple/simple.pb.h` you'll find:

```
/* Maximum encoded size of messages (where known) */
#define SimpleMessage_size                       11
```

And could specify `uint8_t buffer[SimpleMessage_size];`.

This define will be available only if all repeated and string fields have  been specified `(nanopb).max_count` and `(nanopb).max_size` options.

For many practical purposes, you can pick a buffer size that you estimate will be large enough, and handle error conditions. It is also possible to use `pb_get_encoded_size()` to calculate the encoded size and dynamically allocate storage, but in general that is not a great solution in embedded applications. When total system memory size is limited, it is often better to have a constant sized buffer that you can test with, instead of having the available amount of dynamic memory vary at the runtime.

Comment: big thx :) fast, simple, clear, and sufficient/complete